# How does ssh work if client doesn't have identity and public key file?

Tags: server, ssh, remote-login

I was trying to connect to a remote host from a brand new local client via ssh. The remote host had a requirement that *client* need to put it's public key in remote host's `authorized_keys` file. Now, since the client is new and doesn't have any public key in it's `.ssh` directory, I was curious as which public key was being sent to remote - if at all?

@mgor mentioned in a [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/651388/could-not-find-id-rsa-pub#comment-935666) that:

> The server side does not necessarily need a public and private key in the .ssh directory.

I know I can generate new keys, but that's not the question. I just want to know how it works when you don't have any identity and public key file(?).

I tried with `ssh -v` but couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: Then it falls back to whatever other authentication methods are available (password, for example). You'll see exactly what it does in `ssh -v` (e.g., `debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password`, `debug1: Next authentication method: password`)

Comment: The comment by @mgor is correct. It wouldn’t have the private key of any client. It would need a public key for any client using that method of authentication.

Comment: thanks @muru for explanation. little bit more - so `Next authentication method: password` is basically means ssh session is going to use symmetric encryption? and with `publickey` it would use asymmetric encryption? or that's totally independent of the method used for authentication?